# Rounding price based off price + tax result

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in mssql that has price and tax% of items. I've been set with the task of rounding all of the items to where price + tax is equal to the nearest nickle based off of the calculation of (price(tax_percent/100)+price). The problem I'm coming across is that they want to update the price before the calculation to find the best result, for example:

```
price     tax_percent     price_tax_included     **Result**
1.05      8.25%           1.13                   price=1.07(price + tax = 1.15)
1.02      8.25%           1.10                   Don't change, already rounded
1.12      8.25%           1.21                   price=1.11(Price + tax = 1.20)
```

I cant figure out the best way to check what to change the price to for the calculation to work out to the nearest nickle as well as round based on if its below .02 or above .03 cents.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted and explain why it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Since a nickel is 1/20th of a dollar.  The math is simple... go small to lose the precision, and then bring it back up with a rounded amount.

```
Declare @Amt money = 1.13
select round(@Amt*.2,2)/.2
```

Returns

```
1.1500000
```

Comment: elegant as ever john.

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for the grin.

Comment: Jeez john, why you gotta make everything so nice and simple?

Comment: Alright I've found a way to make your answer 2 characters smaller. `round(price_tax_included/5,2)*5` two less '.'

Comment: @SqlZim Even better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)** with `%`

rextester: **http://rextester.com/MUJSMD91030**

```
create table nickels (price_tax_included decimal(9,2))
insert into nickels values (1.20),(1.21),(1.22),(1.23),(1.24),(1.25)

select price_tax_included
  , toNickels = price_tax_included
        + case when        price_tax_included % 0.05 > .02 
               then  0.05-(price_tax_included % 0.05)
               else -1.00*(price_tax_included % 0.05)
           end
  from nickels
```

Comment: Great use of mod Zim